# How to understand the body object properties returned from SharePoint connector actions?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

When I perform an Action using the SharePoint connector, in the Flow run area, I can see the `Raw outputs` that are returned from the Action, for example when using [Move file](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#move-file):

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        // header properties here  
    },
    "body": {
        "ItemId": 50,
        "Id": "%252fMyDocumentLibrary%252fTest%2bdocument_Uploader%2bName.docx",
        "Name": "Test document_Uploader Name.docx",
        "DisplayName": "Test document_Uploader Name.docx",
        "Path": "/MyDocumentLibrary/Test document_Uploader Name.docx",
        "LastModified": "2021-07-06T08:15:56Z",
        "Size": 20922,
        "MediaType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
        "IsFolder": false,
        "ETag": "\"{letters-and-numbers},4\"",
        "FileLocator": "dataset=letters-and-numbers==,id=letters-and-numbers="
    }
}
```

Where can I find out what each of those properties refers to, so that I may pass their values to other Actions when required?

For example, if I wanted to update a file's properties after moving it using [Update file properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#update-file-properties), the required parameters are:

```
Name:  Site Address, Key:  dataset  
Example: https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename

Name:  Library Name, Key:  table  
SharePoint library name

Name:  Id, Key:  id  
Unique identifier of item to be updated

Name:  Item, Key:  item 
Item with changed properties

Name:  Limit Columns by View, Key:  view  
Avoid column threshold issues by only using columns defined in a view
```

Which 'id' returned from [Move file](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#move-file) should be passed through to [Update file properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#update-file-properties)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the actions available for the SharePoint connector are listed here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#actions

If you click on one of the actions, for example [Move file](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#move-file), you can view its parameters, and beneath that what it `Returns`, in this case a [SPBlobMetadataResponse](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#spblobmetadataresponse).

The properties of that response object are listed and described there, ie:

```
ItemId
The value that can be used to Get or Update file properties in libraries.

Id  
The unique id of the file or folder.

Name    
The name of the file or folder.

DisplayName     
The display name of the file or folder.

Path    
The path of the file or folder.

LastModified  
The date and time the file or folder was last modified.

Size  
The size of the file or folder.

MediaType  
The media type of the file or folder.

IsFolder    
A boolean value (true, false) to indicate whether or not the blob is a folder.

ETag    
The etag of the file or folder.

FileLocator  
The filelocator of the file or folder.
```

In this particular instance, it seems the value that you would pass from `Move file` to `Update file properties` is `ItemId`.